# Use of CDK in Codepipeline

Tags: python, aws-cdk

xI have a requirement wherein I need to execute certain CDK command inside the stage. I am not sure on how to use it within a stage

Tried certain things all I can understand is that you can run certain Shell command inside a stage.

```
 with open('<some-config.json>') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        print(lines)
        string_param = aws_ssm.StringParameter(
            self, "StringParameterWithoutSlash",
            parameter_name="<some-config>",
            string_value="{}".format(lines)
        )
```

I have the below CDK pipeline.

```
       pipeline.add_stage(
            stage_name="Source",
            actions=[
                codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitSourceAction(
                    action_name="CodeCommit-Source",
                    repository=code_repo,
                    branch="master",
                    output=source_output,
                )
            ],
        )
        
        pipeline.add_stage(
            stage_name="Build-Test",
            actions=[
                codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction(
                    action_name="Build-Test",
                    project=build_project,
                    input=source_output,
                    outputs=[build_output],
                )
            ],
        )
```

I want to execute certain cdk commands inside the CDK pipeline so that when the pipeline is executed the cdk commands run.

Tried certain things but couldn't find any method that I can use.

Comment: Without some code and more context it will be hard for the community to help you.

Comment: @fedonev added the details

Comment: My understanding:  You have a CDK app with a `codepipeline.Pipeline`. The pipeline's job is to build some (non-CDK) code from a `CodeCommit` repo (`code_repo`).  You want to create a (several?) `ssm.StringParameter` Resource(s) in the stages' environments.  The parameter value inputs are _not known_ to the CDK pipeline app.  The parameter values are in a `.json` file in `code_repo`.  Right?

Comment: @fedonev Yes, this is the need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to run any commands inside a pipeline would be as below.

```
  ssm_deploy_project = codebuild.PipelineProject(
            self, 
            "Jazz Config Deploy",
            environment=codebuild.BuildEnvironment(
                build_image=codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2_2,
            ),
            build_spec=codebuild.BuildSpec.from_object(
            {
            "version": "0.2",
            "phases": {
                "build": {
                    "commands": 'aws ssm put-parameter --name "config-jazz" --overwrite --type String --region eu-central-1 --value "$(cat config-jazz.json)"'
                }
            }
            }
             )
            )
```

update the pipeline.py file to add a new stage

```
   pipeline.add_stage(
                    stage_name="Deploy_Jazz_Config",
                    actions=[
                        codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction(
                            action_name="Jazz-Config-Deploy",
                            project=ssm_deploy_project,
                            input=source_output,
                        )
                    ],
                )
```

This will execute the aws cli from the cdk.

The advantage of using this is that we don't have to manage a separate buildspec.yml file for executing certain cli commands

Answer (score 2):

You can't deploy CDK constructs directly from `codepipeline.Pipeline`.  That's the specialty of the [pipelines.CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html) Construct.  Swapping pipelines isn't necessary, though.

Here's a solution that keeps the OP's `codepipeline.Pipeline`.  It avoids deploying new resources in the pipeline.

1. Add the `ssm.Parameter` Constructs to the CDK Stack. At synth-time the names are known, the values dummy placeholders. The actual parameter values will be set later by a Lambda invoked during the pipeline executions.
2. Add a `Function` Construct to the CDK Stack. The lambda will be called as a pipeline action. The lambda should have an environment variable `PARAMS_JSON`, through which it will receive the params values when invoked. The Lambda's job is to call the boto3 [put_parameter()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.put_parameter) API to overwrite the parameter values with the values in the env var.
3. Set the value of `PARAMS_JSON` using shell commands in a pipeline action. `<some-config.json>` will be available at this time from the input artifacts.
4. Add a [LambdaInvokeAction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.LambdaInvokeAction.html) that refers to the `Function` you added above.  Where exactly in the pipeline you place steps 3 and 4 will depend on the details of your use case.

An advantage of this approach the Parameters and Lambda are tied to the Stack lifecycle.  The parameters will be created, updated and destroyed together with the Stack, even though the Stack does not know the parameter values.

Comment: thanks a lot for the confirmation! that's what I thought as well we cannot invoke cdk inside pipeline. too big a workaround for creating SSM parameter. I was thinking of invoking a post action command using some spec file like builspec.yml(i.e executing a aws cli)